# In plain C, how to assign a void pointer value to a double

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, double, void-pointers

```
void foo(void* p) {
    double d = (double) p; // Doesn’t compile.
    printf(“%f\n”, d);
}
```

What I need is to be able to call

```
foo((void*) 13.0);
```

and have 13.0 printed.

**Note**

I need this in order to store distances (of type double) between source nodes and arbitrary nodes stored in a C hash map that is “void*” generic in graph search. See https://github.com/coderodde/BidirectionalDijkstra4Perl2

Comment: It makes no sense to pass `13.0` as a pointer. Do you mean you want to pass a pointer that, when dereferenced, has that value. It's not clear what you are trying to do. Can you provide more context for why you need to do this.

Comment: You can't to this. You probably should refactor your hash map so it can store `double`s instead of `void*`. Otherwise you could store _pointers_ to `double` which can be converted to and from void pointers, but I'd stromgly advice against this because the void pointers you store in the hash map would point to a single double which needs memory to be allocated for, and this would be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *standard way* has been given by [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362484/3545273).

But if the size of a `void *` is not smaller than the size of a `double`, you can store the representation of the `double` in a `void *`. From that point you cannot use the pointer for anything but extracting back the representation to a `double` object. Here is an example code demonstrating it:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>

void foo(void* p) {
    double d;
    memcpy(&d, &p, sizeof(d));
    printf(" % f\n", d);
}

int main() {
    void* p;
    // ensure that the representation of a double can fit in a void *
    static_assert(sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(double), "sizeof(double) > sizeof(void *)");
    double d = 13.0;
    memcpy(&p, &d, sizeof(d));
    foo(p);
    return 0;
}
```

But **beware**: this should only be used as a workaround to cope with legacy code. The portability is limited to platforms where the size of a double is not greater than the size of a void * which is false on a 32 bits platform. Compiling above code in 32 bits mode raises a compilation error:

```
error ...: sizeof(double) > sizeof(void *)
```

Answer (score 1):

When specification has a means of providing data through `void *`, the way you are usually intended to use it is to allocate memory for the data and pass the address of the memory as a `void *`. Then the software that receives the data converts the `void *` to a pointer to the appropriate type and uses that pointer to access the data in memory.

Thus, if you just need a single `double` value, a way you would do this is:

```
double *p = malloc(sizeof *p);  // Allocate memory for the data.
if (!p)  // Guard against allocation failure.
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, unable to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
*p = 13.0;  // Store data in memory.
foo(p);     // Pass the address of the data to foo.
```

Later, in some routine that was given the address of the data, you would do something like this:

```
void MyCallBackRoutine(void *vp) // Might be "const void *" instead.
{
    double *p = vp;  // Convert to "double *".  Might need "const" with it.
    printf("The conveyed data is %g.\n", *p);
}
```

You should also free the memory when it is no longer needed.

If you need more than just a `double` or other single item, you would create a `struct` containing all the members you needed and put all the data into it.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by doing a little pointer trick

```c
void foo(void *p)
{
    double d = *((double *) &p);

    printf("%f\n", d);
}
```

It works by taking a pointer to p and dereferencing it as a double, so you can convert your void * to a double

But be aware that it's only works if the double and the void * have the same len on the computer your code will be run
Otherwise it cannot works because of [the way double are stored in memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: Note, though, that this would be a strict aliasing violation and could also violate any alignment restrictions.  Those both result in undefined behavior.

Comment: This answer promotes bad coding practices which may produce code that breaks when least expected. To be really helpful to OPs it is best to point out in your answer how to do things correctly and not just try to find an answer that may or may not work